# OpenSessionInViewFilter cascade merge problems

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using OpenSessionInViewFilter, Spring, and Hibernate for data access. 
OpenSessionInViewFilter configured like this

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
            <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>singleSession</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
```

Now I have entity mapped with annotations, something like that

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SERVICE_USER")
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class ServiceUser implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "service_user_id_generator", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "service_user_id_generator", sequenceName = "service_user_id_gen", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "contract_type_id")
    @ForeignKey(name = "service_user_ct_fk")
    private ServiceUserContractType contractType;

}
```

Now i'm trying to construct and save new ServiceUser entity. To do that I have service that retrieves ServiceUserContractType from database and sets corresponding field in newly created service user. Method that gets contarct types from database marked as transactional.

To save service user i use

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(serviceUser)
```

If I try this method to retrive contract type

```
public ServiceUserContractType getContractType(Long id){
        Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(ServiceUserContractType.class);

        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));

        return (ServiceUserContractType) criteria.uniqueResult();
    }
```

Then, the moment merge called i recieve

```
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing
```

exception. I get it, I add `cascade = CascadeType.MERGE` to `@ManyToOne` annotation in Service User mapping and it works. But...
If I use

```
public ServiceUserContractType getContractType(Long id){
        return (ServiceUserContractType) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(ServiceUserContractType.class, id);
    }
```

it works perfectly without cascade merge option.
The only difference that i see while debugging is that first method (with criteria) returns fully loaded contract type entity, and `load` variant returns uninitialized proxy.

Can someone explain how things work in this scenarios? Why proxy can be merged without cascade? Why criteria returns not proxy but fully initialized entity?

Comment: I'm guessing here but maybe in the first scenario the entity hasn't been flushed yet, hence when you fetch it it's still transient. On the second scenario maybe it auto-flushes prior to loading

Comment: Which version of hibernate are you using? We had a similar issue with hibernate cascaded merge and a downgrade of Hibernate version to 4.1.1 resolved our issue.

Comment: Our Hibernate is old 3.6.9.Final. An contract types is basically immutable reference table that can be updated only by direct SQL query. So no flushind and unflushing here. If i undestood you correctly.